# Adding details to Rspec errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using Rspec like this:

```
expect(approx_equals(value, raw_ref[u].fetch(p.to_s).to_f, 30)).to eq(true)
```

`approx_equals` returns a boolean and `30` is a % of margin of error accepted

I am forced to do this way because I am comparing numbers which can change slightly.

But when one of my tests fails, I get an error like this:

```
testing element Foo 0.00000s
expected: true
     got: false

(compared using ==)
```

I would like to add/change some datas into these logs. For instance:

```
testing element Foo 0.00000s
expected: 10
margin of error : 30%
     got: 23
```

Is there a way to override the Rspec traces?

Comment: yes, create your own matcher

Comment: Good solution, thanks, but be_within will be quicker.

Comment: @Pol0nium as you used `expect` instead of `should` please use `expect` for better rspec http://betterspecs.org/#expect  `expect(1..30).to cover(expected)` in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the built-in [`be_within` matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-3/docs/built-in-matchers/be-within-matcher) might fit your needs:

```
it { should be_within(0.5).of(28) }
```

fails with

```
expected 27.5 to be within 0.5 of 28
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this way

First check it is returning integer or not

```
  expect(actual).to be_a_kind_of(Fixnum)
```

Then check the condition

```
 expect(actual).to be >  expected
 expect(actual).to be >= expected
 expect(actual).to be <= expected
 expect(actual).to be <  expected
```

Also in ranges

```
 expect(1..30).to cover(expected)
```

Also if you want to use regexp

```
  expect(actual).to match(/expression/) #in expression \d+ for digit..
```